# Local log-likelihood for multiclass linear regression model

Tags: regression, logistic, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, kernel-smoothing

In page 206 of the book 'Elements of statistical learning', the author wrote:

> *The local log-likelihood for this $J$ class model can be written*
>
> $\sum_{i=1}^NK_\lambda (x_0, x_i)\{\beta_{g_i0}(x_0) + \beta_{g_i}(x_0)^T(x_i-x_0)  - log[1+\sum_{k=1}^{J-1}exp(\beta_{k0}+\beta_k(x_0)^T(x_i-x_0))]\}$

I can understand that the term $K_\lambda (x_0, x_i)$ is there to weight down the log-likelihood of each individual observation, but really don't know why the term $(x_i-x_0)$ instead of only $x_i$ - which I am expecting.

Is this just a typo or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three bullets below, the authors provide the answer:

[image]

Comment: I saw it couple days ago, since I cannot vote up now, thanks for your attention